# How can i delete all the intersecting points of curves in geometry nodes blender?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I was working on a tree generator in geometry nodes but the problem is that I have a lot of intersecting curves.

When I convert the curves to meshes there is a problem with shading and you get a messy mesh.

How can I delete all the points of the curves that have the same position so I don't get a really messy mesh?

[Project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tz4pLREr4NhHddomMG_HmMoojZseF5fR/view?usp=sharing)

Tree generator:
[image: tree]

Messy mesh
[image]
[image]

The nodes
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]